# kmer counts with cython implementation

Tags: cython

I have this function implemented in Cython:

```
def count_kmers_cython(str string, list alphabet, int kmin, int kmax):
"""
Count occurrence of kmers in a given string.
"""
counter = {}
cdef int i
cdef int j
cdef int N = len(string)
limits = range(kmin, kmax + 1)
for i in range(0, N - kmax + 1):
    for j in limits:
        kmer = string[i:i+j]
        counter[kmer] = counter.get(kmer, 0) + 1
return counter
```

Can I do better with cython? Or Can I have any away to improve it?
I am new to cython, that is my first attempt.

I will use this to count kmers in DNA with alphabet restrict to 'ACGT'. The length of the general input string is the average bacterial genomes (130 kb to over 14 Mb, where each 1 kb = 1000 bp).
The size of the kmers will be 3 < kmer < 16.

I wish to know if I could go further and maybe use cython in this function to:

```
def compute_kmer_stats(kmer_list, counts, len_genome, max_e):
"""
This function computes the z_score to find under/over represented kmers 
according to a cut off e-value.
Inputs:
    kmer_list - a list of kmers
    counts - a dictionary-type with k-mers as keys and counts as values.
    len_genome - the total length of the sequence(s).
    max_e - cut off e-values to report under/over represented kmers.
Outputs:
    results - a list of lists as [k-mer, observed count, expected count, z-score, e-value]
"""
print(colored('Starting to compute the kmer statistics...\n',
              'red',
              attrs=['bold']))
results = []
# number of tests, used to convert p-value to e-value.
n = len(list(kmer_list))
for kmer in kmer_list:
    k = len(kmer)
    prefix, sufix, center = counts[kmer[:-1]], counts[kmer[1:]], counts[kmer[1:-1]]
    # avoid zero division error
    if center == 0:
        expected = 0
    else:
        expected = (prefix * sufix) // center
        observed = counts[kmer]
        sigma = math.sqrt(expected * (1 - expected / (len_genome - k + 1)))
        # avoid zero division error
        if sigma == 0.0:
            z_score = 0.0
        else:
            z_score = ((observed - expected) / sigma)
            # pvalue for all kmers/palindromes under represented
            p_value_under = (math.erfc(-z_score / math.sqrt(2)) / 2)
            # pvalue for all kmers/palindromes over represented
            p_value_over = (math.erfc(z_score / math.sqrt(2)) / 2)
            # evalue for all kmers/palindromes under represented
            e_value_under = (n * p_value_under)
            # evalue for all kmers/palindromes over represented
            e_value_over = (n * p_value_over)
            if e_value_under <= max_e:
                results.append([kmer, observed, expected, z_score, p_value_under, e_value_under])
            elif e_value_over <= max_e:
                results.append([kmer, observed, expected, z_score, p_value_over, e_value_over])
return results
```

OBS - Thank you CodeSurgeon by the help. I know there are other tools to count kmer efficiently but I am learning Python so I am trying to write my own functions and code.

Comment: Will try to post something in the next day or two. If the valid alphabet is ascii, can consider using bytes instead of string for (probably) faster indexing. Do you really need to store the k-mer substrings inside counter though, or is just storing the start and end indices enough? Also would double check this, but creating intermediate generator objects (like that limits variable) is slower and you will lose iteration speed.

Comment: Some additional questions too. Is there any domain specific information we can apply to this problem? For example, is it fair to assume that the alphabet can be restricted to nucleotides (ACGT)? If so, then your string representations could be even more compact than raw python strings. How long are the typical inputs (parent string, kmer)? If the parent string is short, maybe overallocating by making a 2d array of counts could make indexing faster at the expense of wasting memory.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, that 2d array approach would not really work to help you get the counts. I would look into implementing a specialized "trie" data structure. That should facilitate searching to see if a kmer exists as well once the trie is built for quick lookups.

Comment: I went through the exact same problem, but i limited the kmer to 3<= k <=5. Do NOT use dictionary in Cython, those are very slow compared to C structures.  I implemented it for [my work](https://github.com/sylvain-ri/PLoT-ME/blob/master/plot_me/cython_module/cyt_ext.pyx), let me know if I should post a complete answer explaining it. I used plain arrays and computed addresses based on the nucleotides.

Comment: As said CodeSurgeon, if you have a limited number of kmers to find, to can allocate an array to count them. If you number of kmers become very large, then you better look into existing solutions such Jellyfish

Comment: Took a long while to implement an initial version of that trie approach I outlined in my previous comment, but it is not much better than your initial approach (only about 1.7-1.8x faster) and has significantly more custom code. You can take a look at it [here](https://github.com/AnishN/kmercy). Still feel like there is some more room for optimization though.

Comment: I will check it out @CodeSurgeon...And thanks for your time and effort! Take care bro...